# Run SQL Select query from .sql file using VBA in Excel

Tags: sql, oracle, vba, excel, excel-2007

To create dynamic select statements I am currently creating a temp file to hold the query (30k + characters due to number of joins and decodes being used). I'd like to use this temp file that has the full select statement to return the data into excel.

Using my current code I can only run a short select statements. The strings I create seem to get truncated for some reason.

Here's the snippet of code I'm using that creates the file and currently attempts to run the same string.

```
' Set file details
fileDir = "C:\temp\"
filePath = "C:\temp\" & node & "_SRO_TCs.sql"

'check if directory exists, if not create it
If Dir(fileDir, cbDirectory) = "" Then
MkDir fileDir
End If

' open the file
Open filePath For Output As #1

'Write to file
outputText = sqlQuery3
Print #1, outputText

'open connection
sqlCon.ConnectionString = Conn
  'Cn.CursorLocation = adUseClient
sqlCon.Open

'set and execute sql command
Set sqlCommand.ActiveConnection = sqlCon
sqlCommand.CommandText = sqlQuery3
sqlCommand.CommandType = adCmdText
sqlCommand.Execute

'open recordset
Set sqlRecordSet.ActiveConnection = sqlCon
sqlRecordSet.Open sqlCommand


'copy data to excel
ActiveSheet.Range("A1").CopyFromRecordset (sqlRecordSet)  <<<< This is where i get an error returned when stepping through the code - "Run-time error '91': Object variable or With block variable not set"

'close connections
sqlRecordSet.Close
sqlCon.Close

'Close file
Close #1
```

When I check the file created it has a working sql select statement. I'd like to be able to run this file or the string. Please help!

Comment: You are opening the file for output and writing sqlQuery3 to the file. Do you mean to read the file into a string variable called sqlQuery3?

Comment: @Remou sqlQuery3 is the query that is being written into a file, it already contains the select string. i'd like a way to use the file created instead of sqlQuery3 because sqlQuery3 gets truncated when i try to pass it through the sqlCommand.

Comment: @Tony - I think you are mistaken about that truncation.  Why do you think your SQL is getting truncated? The only limit I've ever run into is the maximum size of a single Oracle SQL query which is **much** larger than 256 characters.

Comment: @TimWilliams the sql query i'm using is 30,500+ characters long. If i use the same vba code and truncate the query to be shorter (which doesn't do what i need it to, just for testing) the code works without error.  When the query is long i run into a multitude of errors.. Either way, the question is, how do i run a sql query from a .sql file without loading into a string variable?

Comment: To use ADO to run the query you'd have to load the SQL into a string, so you're back to square one.  Have you checked to ensure your sqlRecordset isn't EOF before copying it to the worksheet?

Comment: @TimWilliams how do i check to ensure my sqlRecordset isn't EOF before copying it to the worksheet?

Comment: @Tony - `If Not sqlRecordset.EOF Then ActiveSheet.Range("A1").CopyFromRecordset sqlRecordSet Else Msgbox "No records returned!" End If`

Comment: @TimWilliams I commented out my line of code that was giving me the other error and add the lines you gave me and i get an error: "Operation is not allowed when the object is closed"

Answer (score 0):

The Command Execute method looks like this

```
Set recordset = command.Execute( RecordsAffected, Parameters, Options )
```

Your code is quite different.  Hadn't looked too hard at your code before, because you said it worked with a shorter SQL statement.